# Shell to resolve output issue - issue in concatenation and file reading

Tags: file, shell

I have a quick question - I am trying to resolve an issue with a serie of files where the output has been changed.

The output should look like that:

```
>Tests HadI-sdds1:4134:AAABBBBB:1:1101:6635:2407_2:N:0:TTTTTT
AAAABBBBBEEEECCCCERTTSFASFASFDSGFSDGGSFGFSGDFGDFGDFGDFGDFGDFGDFGDCCVBWAAAABBBBBEEEECCCCERTTSFASFASFDSGFSDGGSFGFSG
```

But appears as:

```
>Tests HadI-sdds1:4134:AAABBBBB:1:1101:6635:2407_2:N:0:TTTTTT
AAAABBBBBEEEECCCCERTTSFASFASFDSGFSDGGSFGFSGDFGDFGDFGDFGDFGDFGDFGDCCVBW
AAAABBBBBEEEECCCCERTTSFASFASFDSGFSDGGSFGFSG
```

I have written the following code to try to fix it, but the line 16 appears to return an empty string, however when I do the echo without putting in a var, I get the complete line.

```
#!/bin/sh 
FILENAME=$1
OUTPUT=$2
set LineToWrite=''

while read LINE 
do
if  [ `echo "$LINE" | awk '{print substr($0,1,1)}'` == ">" ]
    then
        echo "$LineToWrite" >> $OUTPUT
        echo "$LINE" >> $OUTPUT
        set LineToWrite=''
    else
        set currLine=`echo "$LINE" | awk '{print substr($0,1,70)}'`
        set LineToWrite+=$currLine
fi
done <$FILENAME
```

Any Idea to solve my problem? (The files contains > 1million lines)

Thanks a lot in advance!!!!

Comment: Is the problem that there is 1 space in the third line between 'W A...' and you want to remove it? Also, is each line of data defined as beginning with the '>' char? Are there really linebreaks embedded in the records? If not, better to edit your sample data down to something that illustrates the problem with each record appearing on one line above. Seems like 1 awk program could handle all of this, but your description is too hard to follow. Good luck.

Comment: It's a line break between line 2 (ending by W) and 3 (starting by A) it's just stackoverflow that does not show the sample correctly. Every first line should start by ">" and should not be changed.

Comment: There's no need to use awk to test if the string begins '>': `if test "$LINE" != "${LINE#>}"; then ...`

Comment: So your problem is that you have a break in a line of data and you need to join the split record back together again? Als my point about your sample data is "Do you need to be so literal about "My data is broken""? We can't tell what the real problem is. Consider editing you post to use a shorter set of fake data that makes it easy to see what is a good line of data and what is bad/broken line.  Good luck.

Comment: Is the above a correct representation of the data problem you're trying to fix? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Three things :

- no space allowed between keys & values in shell
- use more quotes on all variables
- no need to cat FILE | while : use `while <condition>; do ...; done < FILE`

*USE MORE QUOTES!* They are vital. Also, learn the difference between ' and " and `. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: Hi Sputnick,
I have updated as you described, but still no changes :/
    #!/bin/sh 
    FILENAME=$1
    OUTPUT=$2
    set LineToWrite=''
   
    while read LINE 
    do
    if  [ `echo $LINE | awk '{print substr($0,1,1)}'` == ">" ]
     then
      echo $LineToWrite >> $OUTPUT
   echo $LINE >> $OUTPUT
   set LineToWrite=''
  else
    set currLine=`echo $LINE | awk '{print substr($0,70,1)}'`
    set LineToWrite+=$currLine
    fi
    done <$FILENAME

Comment: `echo "$VAR"` instead of `echo $VAR` on **every variables**

Comment: Updated ;) it still doesn't return anything :/